# Extend a base class and narrowing propery type

Tags: typescript

For example I have a base class representing an animal owner :

```
abstract class AnimalOwner {
    public name: string;
    public animal: Animal;
}
type Animal = {
    type: Dog | Cat | Fish,
    foo: string,
    bar: string,
};
```

Then I have a class that extends this base class but need to narrow the type of `animal` property to only `Dog` :

```
class DogOwner extends AnimalOwner {
    // Here animal.type should be only Dog
}
```

I'm not sure how to declare it on the `DogOwner` class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generic for that :

```
enum AnimalType {
    Dog, Cat, Fish
}

abstract class AnimalOwner<T extends AnimalType> {
    public name!: string;
    public animal!: Animal<T>;
    type!: T;
}
type Animal<T extends AnimalType> = {
    type: T
    foo: string,
    bar: string,
};

class DogOwner extends AnimalOwner<AnimalType.Dog> {}

const dog = new DogOwner().animal.type
//    ^? AnimamType.Dog
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCWECGAbAKgTwA7CgbwFgAoKUqAEQHsBzAGigGEkAXegMXgGcALYgX2LEkAI07MATkgDGzKFJRJOnWAmQoA8gHcQwcQB40UYAA9moACbK4iVJhwA%20fMTJQsYYSnhSoIJBGAAhABcUGLi8CDUANzOZG4eXlBIqqjBKjYoBvYxJGTM2IEhaDkCRPk46WoGRqYWVinoBY4AvE65pOXARbGkAGaUlCFhEXQ9UMJI4kMSI7T8OcTyispU1Fo64jVmIJaVqOu6etZqdsAAdKuOeKWLlCBiUOY0UK06mhQ0B%20IAFACUZ8kMmdOsQAPSglwAPQA-EA)